# MySQL - Recursive CTE to fill in gaps in data over time

Tags: sql, mysql, common-table-expression

I am currently facing an issue that I have been trying to crack for a while now without success.
The problem is as follows:

I have a table that tracks requests and their status changes over time. Over a period of time the request will be changing and getting new status, and for each time it changes status there will be a new record on the table.
The table structure is as follows:

request_id int
from_status char(1)
to_status char(1)
request_date date

I'm working on a report that has to show, for each day, how many open requests there were and in which status. The problem? I only have a record with a date of when the status was changed. If a request was opened with no new status for a few days, I will only see it one and I won't be able to aggregate it.

That's where the recursive CTE comes into play. I want to generate the data points that I'm missing from when the request was not changed.

For example, let's say I have this data

| request_id | from_status | to_status | date (yyyy-mm-dd) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | A | B | 2023-01-01 |
| 12345 | B | C | 2023-01-02 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-03 |
| 12345 | D | X | 2023-01-07 |
| 54321 | A | B | 2023-01-06 |
| 54321 | B | C | 2023-01-09 |

So, if I just do a count on the to_status columns and group per date, I will get that I had one request with status B on the 01/01, one request with status C on the 02/01, one with status D on the 01/03, and one with status X on the 07/01, but I will be missing the 4th, 5th and 6th while it should also be showing one request.

My idea was to use a recursive CTE to "duplicate" some data and generate data for the missing days, so I can aggregate them. It should show something like this:

| request_id | from_status | to_status | date (yyyy-mm-dd) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | A | B | 2023-01-01 |
| 12345 | B | C | 2023-01-02 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-03 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-04 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-05 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-06 |
| 12345 | D | X | 2023-01-07 |
| 54321 | A | B | 2023-01-06 |
| 54321 | A | B | 2023-01-07 |
| 54321 | A | B | 2023-01-08 |
| 54321 | B | C | 2023-01-09 |

Then I could aggregate the data and get the correct values for the report, but I'm having some troubles getting the recursive CTE to work.

**Notes: The table has multiple IDs, is not just one. So the solution has to consider that**

Thank you very much for your time!

## Edit

I've come to something that I think could be a viable solution.

```
SELECT * FROM requests
```

| request_id | date | from_status | to_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2023-01-01 | A | B |
| 12345 | 2023-01-02 | B | C |
| 12345 | 2023-01-03 | C | D |
| 12345 | 2023-01-07 | D | X |
| 54321 | 2023-01-04 | D | X |
| 54321 | 2023-01-01 | D | X |

```
with recursive cte as (
      select request_id, from_status, to_status,date,
  DATE_ADD(lead(date) over (PARTITION BY request_id order by date), INTERVAL -1 DAY) as last_date
      from requests
      union all
      select request_id, from_status, to_status,
  date_add(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY), last_date
      from cte
      where date < last_date
     )
select *
from cte
order by request_id, date;
```

| request_id | from_status | to_status | date | last_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | A | B | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-01 |
| 12345 | B | C | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-02 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-06 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-06 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-05 | 2023-01-06 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-06 | 2023-01-06 |
| 12345 | D | X | 2023-01-07 | *null* |
| 54321 | D | X | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-03 |
| 54321 | D | X | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-03 |
| 54321 | D | X | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-03 |
| 54321 | D | X | 2023-01-04 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ehOz8If2?hide=12)

I apply a LEAD window function and partition it by the request_id and order it by the date, and on top of that I build the recursive CTE.

It is functional, but I do worry a little about how well would this approach scale, as the tables I'm working with have millions of rows.

Can anybody think of a better way to get the data with less impact?

Comment: What is `date` in your code?

Comment: Is a called called date with the datatype date. I find it odd that date is not a reserved keyword as it is in sql server and can make the code a bit confusing... My bad for posting a bad example, sorry! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  request_id INT,
  from_status CHAR(1),
  to_status CHAR(1),
  `date` DATE
  );
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(12345, 'A',    'B',    '2023-01-01'),
(12345, 'B',    'C',    '2023-01-02'),
(12345, 'C',    'D',    '2023-01-03'),
(12345, 'D',    'X',    '2023-01-07');
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| request_id | from_status | to_status | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | A | B | 2023-01-01 |
| 12345 | B | C | 2023-01-02 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-03 |
| 12345 | D | X | 2023-01-07 |

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT MIN(`date`) `date`, MAX(`date`) `stop` FROM test
  UNION ALL
  SELECT `date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY, `stop` FROM cte WHERE `date` < `stop`
)
SELECT data.request_id, data.from_status, data.to_status, cte.`date`
FROM cte
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT *
  FROM test
  WHERE test.`date` <= cte.`date`
  ORDER BY test.`date` DESC LIMIT 1
) data
```

| request_id | from_status | to_status | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | A | B | 2023-01-01 |
| 12345 | B | C | 2023-01-02 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-03 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-04 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-05 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-06 |
| 12345 | D | X | 2023-01-07 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FU04x2fa)

---

> That wouldn't work if there are multiples ids in the table. ... – DerDot

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  request_id INT,
  from_status CHAR(1),
  to_status CHAR(1),
  `date` DATE
  );
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(12345, 'A',    'B',    '2023-01-01'),
(12345, 'B',    'C',    '2023-01-02'),
(12345, 'C',    'D',    '2023-01-03'),
(12345, 'D',    'X',    '2023-01-07'),
(54321, 'A',    'B',    '2023-01-06'),
(54321, 'B',    'C',    '2023-01-09');
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| request_id | from_status | to_status | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | A | B | 2023-01-01 |
| 12345 | B | C | 2023-01-02 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-03 |
| 12345 | D | X | 2023-01-07 |
| 54321 | A | B | 2023-01-06 |
| 54321 | B | C | 2023-01-09 |

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT request_id, MIN(`date`) `date`, MAX(`date`) `stop` FROM test GROUP BY 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT request_id, `date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY, `stop` FROM cte WHERE `date` < `stop`
)
SELECT data.request_id, data.from_status, data.to_status, cte.`date`
FROM cte
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT *
  FROM test
  WHERE test.request_id = cte.request_id AND test.`date` <= cte.`date`
  ORDER BY test.`date` DESC LIMIT 1
) data
ORDER BY 1,4
```

| request_id | from_status | to_status | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | A | B | 2023-01-01 |
| 12345 | B | C | 2023-01-02 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-03 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-04 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-05 |
| 12345 | C | D | 2023-01-06 |
| 12345 | D | X | 2023-01-07 |
| 54321 | A | B | 2023-01-06 |
| 54321 | A | B | 2023-01-07 |
| 54321 | A | B | 2023-01-08 |
| 54321 | B | C | 2023-01-09 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qd28c7dQ)

Comment: That wouldn't work if there are multiples ids in the table. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sbqaRbRv). You need to do apply some window function and partition by the request_id. I've come to something very close to a solution [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/w1RV0IB4) I think

Comment: @DerDot The question deals with single `id`. If your question is not adequate then ask another one.

Comment: I mean on one hand I do get your point, in my example I only listed one id. I was trying to simplify the code in the question. It didn't even crossed my mind that somebody would think that the whole table would only have one ìd`.
But thank you for pointing that out, I've edited the question to try and better reflect what the dataset looks like.

Comment: @DerDot Editing the question when the answer for its old version presents is not a good practice.. anycase, provide sample source data as ready-to-use CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (or as a link to online fiddle), not as a table only.